# Custom Authorization Attribute catch requested Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, forms-authentication

When making a custom `[Authorize]` attribute is there a way to catch what Role that is being requested?

So in the case of `[Auth(Roles = "IgnoreAuth")]` is there a way inside of the custom `Auth` to catch `"IgnoreAuth"` somehow?

Comment: Just check for Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name)

Comment: @RamanZhylich I don't want to get the roles for a user... I need the role being requested.

Comment: what you meany by *role being requested*?

Comment: @Mark when you annotate an Action with `[Authorize(Roles = "Something")]`.  I'm wanting to find what Roles is equal to and in that case "`Something`" is what I'm wanting to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles is in the base AuthorizeAttribute class.  So you can simply access it from your custom Auth like this:

```
public class AuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var roles = this.Roles;
    }
}
```

Just to clarify, whenever you do [Auth(Roles = "IgnoreAuth")], you're just setting the Roles property in the AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: will this give me the roles for the user that's logged in or will it give me the Role that is actively being checked against at that time of the request?

Comment: It will give you whatever you pass into it, which would be "IgnoreAuth" in your case.